# Create python proactive messaging with microsoft bot framework

Tags: python, botframework

What are the steps to create a push notification/proactive messaging bot using Python with microsoft bot framework? Since there's no official documentation yet, I don't really know where to start.

I have imported the following:

```
from botbuilder.schema import Activity, ActivityTypes, ConversationReference
```

How can it be used and what's a very simple example?

Comment: Proactive messaging is when a bot sends a message to a user that's not a direct response to a message the user sent to the bot. Push notifications are a system that mobile apps use to notify the user through the device. While these are two different things, do you just mean you want the bot to message the user through a Bot Framework channel and have the chat client hopefully send a push notification if the user has given the right permissions and enabled the right settings?

Answer (score 0):

I worked a sample demo which based on [state management sample](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python/tree/master/samples/45.state-management) for you .
Pls follow the setps to make it work : 
1.Adding code below into `app.py` :

```
@APP.route("/api/notify", methods=["POST"])
def notify():
    if request.headers["Content-Type"] == "application/json":
        body = request.json
    else:
        return Response(status=415)

    activity = Activity().deserialize(body)

    auth_header = (
        request.headers["Authorization"] if "Authorization" in request.headers else ""
    )

    async def aux_func(turn_context):
        await BOT.on_turn(turn_context)

    try:
        task = LOOP.create_task(
            ADAPTER.process_activity(activity, auth_header, aux_func)
        )
        LOOP.run_until_complete(task)
        return Response(status=201)
    except Exception as exception:
        raise exception
```

2.Modify function `on_message_activity` in `state_management_bot.py` as code below

```
async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
    # Get the state properties from the turn context.

    if(turn_context.activity.channel_id != 'notify'):
       await turn_context.send_activity("You asid:" + turn_context.activity.text);
    else:
       await turn_context.send_activity("You get a notify : "+ turn_context.activity.text);
```

3. Run this sample locally on Azure bot emulator, click the message from bot and note the conversation id and serviceUrl : 
   [image]

Use postman or restclient to do a post call to trigger the notify endpoint with json content :

```
{
    "text": "this is a notify sent from outside ",
    "textFormat": "plain",
    "type": "message",
    "channelId": "notify",
    "from": {
      "id": "backend",
      "name": "xxxxx",
      "role": "xxxxxx"
    },
    "conversation": {
      "id": "<conversation id>"
    },
    "recipient": {
      "id": "",
      "name": "bot",
      "role": "bot"
    },
    "serviceUrl": "<service URL>"
  }
```

Result : 
[image]
[image]